# Is there any way to access other class objects using ids in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm making a method that changes the language in my Kivy app.

I am trying to get access to objects from the other classes using **ids**.

part of my .py code:

```
    class SettingsScreen(Screen):
        def change_langg(self):

           #MainMenu screen
           self.main = MenuScreen()
           self.exit_but = self.main.ids['exit']
           #Settings screen
           self.back1_but = self.ids['back1']
           self.lang_but = self.ids['language']
           self.fullscr_but = self.ids['fullscr']

           if self.lang_but.text == 'Бг':

              #Main menu screen
               self.exit_but.text = 'Изход'
               #Settings screen
               self.back1_but.text = 'Назад'
               self.fullscr_but.text = 'Цял екран'
               self.lang_but.text = 'En'

           elif self.lang_but.text == 'En':
              #Main menu screen
              self.exit_but.text = 'Exit'
              #Settings screen
              self.back1_but.text = 'Back'
              self.fullscr_but.text = 'Fullscreen'
              self.lang_but.text = 'Бг'
```

I expected the text to change in both screens, but it changes only in the Settings screen. As I mentioned above, I don't have any errors, all ids are correct. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in order to get meaningful answers. But, having said that, your line `self.main = MenuScreen()` creates a new instance of `MenuScreen`. If a `MenuScreen` already appears in your gui, then this new instance does not refer to the displayed instance, and any modifications to the new instance will have no effect on the displayed instance.

Comment: @JohnAnderson You are right.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that works even after the screen has been displayed. The code and comments should be self explanatory, else contact me on unclear parts

```
othrscrn = '' #global variable where the memory location of the other screen can be saved

    class OtherScreen(Screen):
        def __init__(self, *args): #init method to run immediately the code is started
            super(OtherScreen, self).__init__(*args)
            global othrscrn #declaring variable 'othrscrn' a global variable
            othrscrn = self #saving the class' memory location to global variable 'othrscrn'

    class Settings(Screen):
            def change_lang(self):
                global othrscrn #accessing the variable 'othrscrn'
                x = othrscrn #instanciating the class as a new variable x
                lan = x.ids['language'] #acessing the class' ids using its ids
                lan.text = ''#any chnage you want to implement
```